# How to fix "cannot import name np_utils" error on importing keras

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to import keras and getting ImportError: cannot import name np_utils.

How do i fix this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this in a console

```
pip install tensorflow keras numpy np_utils
```

add `sudo` if you're on Linux

Comment: I did read about np_utils earlier but it was not working until i restarted my jupyter session.

That works thanks.